# Latitude and Longitude Returned from the Web Service

Tags: ios, swift

I am consuming a web service which returns the JSON with the following information:

```
   "StreetNum": "6400",
   "StreetName": "Aldine-Bender Road",
   "StreetType": " 
   "Zip": "77396",
   "Park_Acres": 0.00696505,
   "AcreSource": "GIS Value",
   "Editor": "JDegelia",
   "Park_Type": "CSTs/Spaceway",
   "OBJECTID_1": 1,
   "Latitude": 13904515.9456177,
   "Longitude": 3142086.10097251
```

I am interested in both Latitude and Longitude values, but I think they are wrong and do not point to anything! Do Latitude and Longitude look correct to you people? Does it require me to divide by something to get the correct lat and long values?

UPDATE:

Web service URL: http://cohgis.mycity.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/59d52cd8fa9d463ea7cf9f3c0a0c6ea2_11.geojson

Comment: The latitude is a number between -90 and 90 and the longitude is between -180 and 180.

Comment: That numbers seem *a bit* too large...

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I am not sure why the web service is returning that and what those values represent. It says Latitude and Longitude but those values are too large.

Comment: Have you used regex before?

Comment: It might be in radians and maybe I have to convert to degrees!

Comment: are you using a public web service or some custom one? meaning: can we see the actual output ourselves?

Comment: Might be some other form i agree, but i have never worked with other formats to answer that question. 
Here is some more info about coordinates, maybe it will help: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: you should reuqest the web service provider on this issue. We cannot assume something without any reference!

Comment: http://cohgis.mycity.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/59d52cd8fa9d463ea7cf9f3c0a0c6ea2_11.geojson

Comment: The correct lat lon format is inside the Polygon type, but i am not familiar with the other format. Would suggest to contact their support and acquire explanation.

Comment: Thanks Dejan! Yeah the polygon is for creating overlay. I guess I can use that for time being.

Comment: You are welcome, if i find something related to that "strange" format i will write it here.

Comment: Related, but not an exact duplicate: [Google Maps and GeoJSon: latitude and longitude conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11205333/1445366)

Comment: One more thing you can rule out:  Take the values modulo 90.  The results don't line up with the zip code of your example at all.

Comment: I've seen spherical coordinates in radians, but those values would be less than 2pi (about 6.28) for any point on the surface.  It ain't that either.